# SharePoint Calculated field third value

Tags: sharepoint

I have a sharepoint calculated field that looks at two other fields to derive its value...

```
=IF(AND(app_pr_apr01_status="approved",app_pr_apr02_status="approved"),"approved","pending")
```

BUT I have a third need and that is if both values are initial the value should be initial

Answer (score 0):

you have then to start another if condition on the else of your if

following :

=IF(condition,True,False)

you have to do this :

=IF(Condition,true,IF(Condition,True,False))

result =

```
=IF(AND(app_pr_apr01_status="approved",app_pr_apr02_status="approved"),"approved",IF(AND(app_pr_apr01_status="Initial",app_pr_apr02_status="Initial"),"Initial","pending"))
```